# Setting primary color for Android Wear app

Tags: android, wear-os, android-theme

I am creating an android wear app and am trying to set it's primary color. I create and set a theme the same way as for a mobile app. Every attribute is changed correctly except for the primary color. It will always be the default teal color that android uses. I am using the same theme on the companion app and it works there. Is there something I am missing that is done differently in wear? Is there something that could override this setting?

I have tried changing the parent theme to material or Compact.app.

Android Manifest:

```
    <application
    android:name="com.turndapage.navmedia.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Nav">
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Nav" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <!-- your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!-- darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!-- theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/Viewport_Background</item>
</style>
```

colors.xml

```
<resources>
<color name="primary">#8c6354</color>
<color name="Viewport_Background">#4d362e</color>
<color name="primary_dark">#66483d</color>
<color name="Action">#a67563</color>
<color name="accent">#a1887f</color>
<color name="Background_Shaded">#000000</color>
<color name="background">#000000</color>
<color name="digital_text">#ffffff</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `android:` prefix versions:

```
<style name="Theme.Nav" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
  <!-- your app branding color for the app bar -->
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
  <!-- darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
  <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
  <!-- theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
  <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/primary</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/Viewport_Background</item>
</style>
```

The non-namespaced verisons are used by AppCompat, which is not needed or used on Android Wear (`Theme.DeviceDefault` extends `Theme.Material` on Wear devices).

The `colorPrimary` is not used in any surfaces by default, so you'd still need to manually reference it via `?android:attr/colorPrimary` for the background of a view for instance.

Note that you cannot change the background color of notifications in the stream as per [this post](https://plus.google.com/117307096684913371699/posts/1qrcMvBhRHP) - however, the [notification color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)) will be used when the user taps into the notification (assuming you haven't set a content intent - in those cases, they'll just go into your app).

Comment: I tried your example and I didn't see a difference. I also tried using `parent="@android:style/Theme.Material"` but neither worked. Every color but colorPrimary is working.

Comment: `colorPrimary` doesn't show up in any of the built in widgets, but it is certainly available for your own usage via `?android:attr/colorPrimary`. Where were you expecting it to show up?

Comment: I'm looking on the Android Developers page. https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html According to the documentation, it should be showing up in the toolbar. It does in the mobile version. I am mainly interested in changing the notification color since this is supposed to identify my app at a glance. I could set any part of the UI manually if I want, but I am assuming it should affect the action drawers but it is not.

Comment: 1. There's no toolbar on Android Wear devices. 2. Notifications in the stream on Wear 2.0 won't show your color as per [this post](https://plus.google.com/117307096684913371699/posts/1qrcMvBhRHP) - only when you tap through. 3. No, you have to set the `android:background` yourself.

Comment: I guess that thread answers my question. It seems strange that actiondrawers don't use the theme either though. I went back to setting the background manually to the theme. All the documentation I found still showed colored notifications and I still have wear 1.x so wasn't sure what 2.0 should look like. If you want to change your answer, I could mark it as accepted. Adding `android:` in front of the name made no difference.

Comment: Well, the prefix makes all the difference for things like `colorAccent` that do appear in things like `Checkbox`, `Switch`, etc. Your question doesn't actually mention notifications at all, so it seems like if you were expecting an answer about notifications, that would have been something to add to your question.